# Fetching 88 records via DISTINCT from a table of 1.5 million rows is taking 3 seconds

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, distinct

There is a table which are populated from an online service and updated every week.

This goes on a separate (second) database.

The table is like 300MB in size (1.5 million rows) processed by a cron that downloads the CSV data every week. [This CSV file](https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/index.csv) is 3GB in size (4 millions rows) where rows and columns are filtered to retain only a subset of the data. And the order of the columns *may* change. It has in the past. So we can't even predict based on the first row. Even row header names may change.

So its a total dump and filter by some hard-set row names.

In my Django's view which is a DRF powered one, my API URL takes 3 seconds (0:00:03.263031) to execute.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `Region` AS `Region`
FROM `my-table-name`
WHERE `flag` = 'condition'
LIMIT 0, 100
```

Thing is, if it just this endpoint that I'm fetching on the page it wouldn't kill. But there are many endpoints on the single page which are fetched when the user clicks on an INPUT element. And 3 seconds for each trigger is way too long.

What else can I do to optimize the table / query ?

[image]

Comment: What database system and version?

Comment: Server version: 8.0.32 - MySQL Community Server - GPL on localhost - eventually this would be on Azure VM with the latest version of 8 on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: 3 seconds for 1.5M rows -- Not bad.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding an [index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) that covers your query like so:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_MyTableName_Flag_Region ON MyTableName (Flag, Region)
```

This index leads with the `Flag` column because it is a predicate in your `WHERE` clause. Then it follows with the `Region` field so that it's also included, since you're `SELECT`ing that field.

Comment: Thanks - it got reduced to 0.80 seconds.

Comment: @anjanesh No problem! Indexing is super helpful and important to understand. Reading through the docs I linked should be helpful in the future.

Comment: I have indexed one column alone in the past - didnt figure about indexing more than one column in a single index.

Comment: @anjanesh Cool, yea, when it's more than one field in the index they call that a composite index or compound index sometimes.